# How can I create a search bar like this

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, searchbar

The search bar I like is the search bar of meetup.com, how can I create a search bar like that?

[Meetup.com search bar][1]

Sorry, I'm just a beginner in HTML and CSS and I'm still learning it, please help.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4mqI.png

Comment: Hi @JesseKing. Do you want to implement just the search bar itself? Or the dropdown functionality when you click on the searchbar?

Comment: The dropdown functionality with criteria.

Comment: 1. google how to show/hide dropdowns when a button is selected. 2. google text input field events

Comment: Thank you, I found it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap to make it. Here is a quick search bar in [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse">
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </form>
</nav>
```